# Credit Card Verification Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am having some issues creating a regex for a credit card number verifier in Visual C#.
The numbers for the card need to be separated by dashes(-), the first number must be 1-9, and the second set of numbers must be 1-3. So an example would be 2204-1232-9746-5558, or 1111-1111-1111-1111.

here is what I have so far:

```
    Regex card = new Regex(@"^[1-9][0-9]{2}-[1-3]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$");
        string myCard = txtCard.Text;
        Match m  = card.Match(myCard);

        if(m.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The card number entered is vaild");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The card number entered is an invaild card number...");
        }

        txtCard.Clear();
        txtCard.Focus();
```

Every card number I try gives me the same result, the number is invalid.
Can anyone steer me in the right direction?
Much thanks!

Comment: Where do you tell the regex that you expect 4 digits and not only 1 ?

Comment: Not all credit cards follow the same number pattern.  Unless you plan on forcing your users to follow your pattern, you should really consider an alternative approach, or at least a different regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the regex. It should be

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}-[1-3]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$
```

The {4} is how many of the digits in [] should exist.

You should also note that the second [1-3] is not normal for credit cards. At least from my bank.

I would change the above to this.  You may want to check for speed and if this will work for exactly what you want.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{4}){3}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Finding and Verifying Credit Card Numbers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html), which has an in-depth discussion on this topic. The regular expression proposed there is (after stripping hyphens and spaces):

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?          # Visa
 |  5[1-5][0-9]{14}                  # MasterCard
 |  3[47][0-9]{13}                   # American Express
 |  3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}   # Diners Club
 |  6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}      # Discover
 |  (?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}      # JCB
)$
```